# ERROR [2013] MYSQL SERVER UPGRADE, no termina configuración

Tags: mysql

Durante la actualización de MySQL, hay algo que no me deja finalizarla, por lo tanto, ahora mismo, el servicio esta caido.

El error que recibo es este:

```
Configurando mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 5
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de mysql-server:
 mysql-server depende de mysql-server-5.7; sin embargo:
 El paquete `mysql-server-5.7' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete mysql-server (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
No se escribió un informe «apport» porque el mensaje de error indica que es un mensaje de error asociado a un fallo previo.
                                                                                                                           Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

No termino de entender el porque no me deja finalizar la actualización.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion

Parece ser que alguna de las dependencias asociadas a  MySQL Server estaban rotas, se me generaban logs de 40gb en minutos, la maquina siempre estaba al 20% aunque no hubiese nada trabajando sobre ella, etc.

Por lo tanto, la solución fue, quitar completamente MySQL Server, sacando copia previa de las BBDD de las que me dejo, por medio del Workbench y de las que no, directamente de `/var/lib/mysql`

Una vez quitado, actualicé completamente la maquina, reinstalar MySQL Server y restaure las BBDD. Quitando algún error puntual (había tablas corruptas), va como la seda.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando el error que te muetsra, "problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de mysql-server" he googleado un poco.
Como no se si se pueden poner enlaces a sitios externos, te pongo los comandos que dieron la solución en el hilo de mysql bugs.

Primero ver si está corriendo mysql-common

```
ls /usr/share/mysql-common
```

Segundo instalar mysql-common

```
apt-get install mysql-common
```

Tercero vuelve a ejecutar el update de mysql

Comment: Hola @Juanjo me dice que el servicio esta correcto. Estoy probando a desinstalarlo completamente y volver a instalarlo (MySQL server)

Comment: Al final tuve que reinstalar mysql-server por completo

Comment: Bueno, si te he ayudado en algo, me alegro!

Comment: No mucho, pero se agradece el aporte y que emplearas tu tiempo en escribir.